# convert the type of value in a Map - Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to convert the type of value of Map from Any to String in Scala.

I have code like this

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom


case class Name(FristName: String,LastName: String)

object App29 extends App {


  val name = Name("mark","aden")


  val stringListBuilder = new CanBuildFrom[List[Any], String, List[String]] { def apply(from: List[Any]) = this.apply(); def apply() = List.newBuilder[String] }

  val result = name.getClass.getDeclaredFields.map(_.getName)
    .zip(name.productIterator.toList)(stringListBuilder).toMap


}
```

So I am using CanBuilderForm to essentially convert the return type from Map[String,Any] to Map[String,String] but I don't understand why it throws type mismatch error.

Thanks

Edit-1

I figured out that I could use name.productIterator.map(_.toString) to convert it to string but I would like to know why my CanBuildFrom syntax is wrong and how.

Comment: This [Scala-lang blog](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2017/05/30/tribulations-canbuildfrom.html) might be of interest to you.  In essence, Scala is going to move away from using of `CanBuildFrom` in its on-going language design.

Answer (score 2):

That's not what `CanBuildFrom` is designed to be used for. `CanBuildFrom` is to designed to allow ease of implementation of new collection types. It means methods like `map` can be defined on the trait `GenTraversableLike`, and still be able to return the type of the specific collection instead of having to override it on each subtype like `List` and `Vector` etc, because it uses the `CanBuildFrom` builder for the specific collection and so can do the operation generically.

To use `CanBuildFrom` in the way above will just completely confuse anyone that reads your code, it's not idiomatic at all, and should be avoided - I would never pass a code review if I saw `CanBuildFrom` being used in such a way, if you hadn't explained exactly what you were trying to achieve and shown an example of how to do it another way, it would have taken me a long time to work out what the code was doing even if it did compile and work. Generally, you should only be playing with `CanBuildFrom` instances if you really know what you're doing, and also only deep in utility libraries and frameworks that want to provide reusable functionality, it should almost never appear in application code. In my 6 years of Scala development, I never never once needed to implement my own `CanBuildFrom`, and I've only twice written code that actually does something with `CanBuildFrom` instances.

As for why your code doesn't compile, `zip` requires a `CanBuildFrom` whose second parameter is a tuple of the type of the original collection, and the type of the collection you're passing in, ie, you should be providing a `CanBuildFrom[List[Any], (String, Any), List[(String, String)]]`.